# How to Select & Show Only Year from date (MySQL) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using this currently:

```
Select date from Table
echo "Date: " .$result[$x]['date']. " ";
```

Output:

```
Year: 2012-06-11
```

I want to show this output only:

```
Year: 2012
```

Comment: try explode() and then $array_name[0] will be the year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP date function

```
$date = $result[$x]['date'];
echo "Year: " .date("Y",strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL YEAR function

```
SELECT YEAR('2017-06-11');
```

If the field is a string you can convert it into date and use YEAR() on it:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE('2017-06-11', "%Y-%m-%d")) from table
```